# pandas- get index as a string

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, numpy

For a given df, I know you can access a specific column (say, `column`) from a `df` by doing something like:

```
df.column
```

I wanted to see if you could get the indices in a similar fashion. The first thing I tried was:

```
df.index
```

This returns an index which might look something like:

```
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=5, step=1)
```

I see this has a method `from_range`, but it doesn't seem capable of just extracting the index, as a string, for me. I want the index because I want to migrate it into another table to serve as a key-map. Is there a way to just extract the index directly? In theory I could reset the index and just use the `range(len(df))` as a surrogate, but I'm interested in this just in case I wanted to keep a chaotic index for whatever reason.

Comment: `df.index.tolist()`

Comment: That... was really simple. Thanks.

Comment: `RangeIndex(start=0, stop=5, step=1)` *is a string representation of the index*

Comment: Also, what do you mean when you say "I want the index because I want to migrate it into another table to serve as a key-map." ?